# Yakuake window is not auto-focused after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys, wayland, focus, yakuake

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 with Yakuake dropdown terminal. The terminal opens using a keyboard shortcut, e.g. F12. On my old system, the focus was set automatically on the terminal window, so I could just hit F12 and then start typing commands.

After I updated to Ubuntu 22.04, the keyboard shortcut did not work. I found an answer online that keyboard shortcuts are handled differently on Ubuntu 22.04 and the solution was to set a keyboard shortcut in Settings>Keyboard for F12 with `yakuake` command. That worked to open the terminal, but the focus was still on the previous window. Now I have to click the terminal window to focus it first before I can start typing. Also, I can not just close it using F12 unless I focus it first.

After consulting some other answer on the internet, I tried counter-intuitively disabling the `Use Open/Retract action to focus window` setting in Yakuake. That fixed the window toggle but the focus problem remains the same.

I also tried to edit the desktop file Exec line in order to run yakuake with `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb` as per this suggestion: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/hh99xb/workaround_for_yakuake_in_wayland/ but that also did not help with the focus.

Does anybody know how to fix this? Or should I rather switch to some other terminal since Yakuake was afaik built for KDE and X, and not GNOME and WAYLAND. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yakuake indeed does not work correctly with Gnome Shell running on Wayland. However, there is a Gnome Shell extension, [Yakuake](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4757/yakuake/) by albertvaka, that circumvents these issues, and allows to use Yakuake as intended.

Comment: The default shortcut is F12 so those interested in changing it need to do so in the Gnome Shell Extension settings. Setting it only in the Yakuake settings is not enough.

Comment: Even with the extension the user experience was not perfect, sometimes the popup did not work or focus, so I switched to Guake which works perfectly on Gnome.